# how to turn group / channel entity into a dialog object with telethon?

Tags: python, web-scraping, telethon, telegram-api

I need to get some data about one chat (that is a group or a channel)

the data I want from chat is:
chat id
chat name
chat type (group / channel , public / private)
chat members
etc...

I made already a function that takes the needed data from a dialog object.

but to get a dialog object of a chat I must get all chats, so is there any way I can get a dialog object of just one chat / turn a chat entity into a dialog object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `Dialog` object to get the information you have mentioned. they're all available in the [`Channel`](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/channel.html) object. so you must be having an input entity. you can first do:

```py
entity = client.get_entity(<anything you had before>) # to confirm you have full info
```

you can see the link above or `print(entity.stringify())` to get the desired fields.

the unobvious ones can be:

- `entity.megagroup`: a group.
- `entity.broadcast`: a channel.
- `not entity.username`: private.

to get memebers is a whole different thing, check out [client.get_participants](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.iter_participants)

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, do you know if there is any channel entity parameter that shows if it is private or public?

Comment: It's stated above, if a channel has `entity.username` it's public, if None, it's private.